# How do I align geom_text elements in center of first bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am making a grouped bar chart in ggplot2 and want to put labels from the legend in the topmost group of bars.

My data frame looks like this in comma-separated format.

```
Group,Enrollment,Punished,PunishmentRate,Geography2
Total,2001957,302878,0.1512909618,State
Black,436329,117791,0.2699591363,State
Hispanic,625588,72974,0.1166486569,State
White,855256,96396,0.1127101125,State
Total,151818,14159,0.0932629859,Local
Black,38933,6816,0.175069992,Local
Hispanic,53690,3789,0.0705718011,Local
White,53036,2925,0.055151218,Local
```

In my R script, this dataframe is in the variable `dummy`.

```
ggplot(
  data = dummy,
  aes(
    fill = Geography2,
    x = Group,
    y = PunishmentRate
  )
) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "dodge",
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.5
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(
    aes(
      label = Geography2,
      y = 0
    ),
    position = position_dodge(1),
    hjust = 0
  )
```

The outputted chart looks like this.

[image]

How do I do the following?

1. Center "State" and "Local" vertically in the middle of the bar?
2. Only show the label for the first bar group (the topmost set)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To center the text just use `position_dodge(0.5)` instead of `position_dodge(1)`. And to only have text for the first bar subset the data frame you are giving the `geom_text`.

```
ggplot(data = dummy,
       aes(
         fill = Geography2,
         x = Group,
         y = PunishmentRate
       )
) +
  geom_bar(
    position = "dodge",
    stat = "identity",
    width = 0.5
  ) +
  coord_flip() +
  geom_text(data = subset(dummy, Group == "White"),
            aes(
              label = Geography2,
              y = 0
            ),
            position = position_dodge(0.5),
            hjust = 0
  )
```

Resulting in:
[image]